# String.Format not rendering in view with razor code if nested inside if statement

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I have this code below and if I put the String.Format inside a if statement nothing gets rendered in the view. FYI - if I remove the semi colons from the if statements then there is a red line indicating error. This doesn't happen in the non if statement

```
@{
   TimeSpan span = (ybEvent.UtcDate.AddDays(-1) - DateTime.UtcNow);
}
// this works
@String.Format("{0}d {1}hr {2}min", span.Days, span.Hours, span.Minutes)

// this doesn't work - does not render anything in view
@if (span.Days > 0)
  {
     String.Format("{0}d {1}hr {2}min", span.Days, span.Hours, span.Minutes);
   } else
   {
    if (span.Hours > 0)
    {
        String.Format("{0}hr {1}min", span.Hours, span.Minutes);
    } else
    {
      String.Format("{0}min", span.Minutes);
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try putting it inside a tag:

```
@if (span.Days > 0)
{
    <text>@String.Format("{0}d {1}hr {2}min", span.Days, span.Hours, span.Minutes)</text>
}
else
{
    if (span.Hours > 0)
    {
        <text>@String.Format("{0}hr {1}min", span.Hours, span.Minutes)</text>
    }
    else
    {
        <text>@String.Format("{0}min", span.Minutes)</text>
    }
}
```

The `<text>` tag has a special meaning in Razor, it will not be sent to the output. Of course you could have used any other HTML tag instead such as `<span>` or `<div>` to wrap the output

Comment: ya that worked, but what's better, a text tag or a span tag??

Comment: That will depend on whether you want this tag to be placed inside the resulting markup or not. Use `<text>` if you don't want to wrap the text in the resulting markup in any tag. Use `<span>` or `<div>` if you want to apply some additional styling to the text in the resulting markup.

Comment: not sure what the difference is? I tried with both and they both show the rendered string on the screen!

Comment: Look at the generated HTML. You will not see the `<text>` tag in it because it is an invalid tag. It will not be rendered.